# a quick question to service cloud experts

Tags: servicecloud, service

What is the best way to access the large number of records stored in an external billing system from the salesforce console? A logical approach will be to create a custom tab type URL that displays a search page from the billing system or to create a VF page that retrieves the payment information via Web Service call out?

Comment: Lightning connect?

Comment: A visualforce page displaying the data obtained through a webservice call works well. I've never personally used Lightning Connect, but from the marketing materials, it sounds like it is designed to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning Connect is really great if you want to search records across systems. But keep in mind a few things:

- you cannot push data updates to external systems using this. (at present)
- there is a license fee for this feature
- your external system needs to expose the data in odata format